# Best approach to add custom dialog (Confirm Action dialog) on click of a custom link button

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button

The requirement is to display a confirm Action dialog on click of a custom button that is presently having a visualforce page as its content source,used for sending an email to contact record.If the user select 'Yes' from the dialog box,then the visualforce page should execute & send the email to the contact record,otherwise the visualforce page should not be rendered.

[image: Required Dialog box ,but with yes & no buttons]

Comment: Hi Shobhit. Your question appears to be asking for other people to write code for you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like in your button and use the "Execute JavaScript" and "OnClick JavaScript" options.

```
if(confirm("Are you sure to redirect?");)
 {
   window.location.href = '/_ui/core/email/author/ EmailAuthor?id={!Quote__c.Id}' ; //your redirect url
  //or you can use window.open()
 }
else
{
// other logic here
}
```

Comment: ,how will the Id of the current object be passed,right now the id is not getting passed using this method...

Comment: use this piece of code `id={!Quote__c.Id}` and get id from URL parameter.